# Core data crash immutable object

Tags: ios, core-data, iphonecoredatarecipes

Why does this crash?

```
CategoryOfExpense *newCatEx = (CategoryOfExpense *) [NSEntityDescription entityForName:kCategoryOfExpense inManagedObjectContext:moc];
newCatEx.name = self.nameTextField.text; <- crashes here
newCatEx.icon =  [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.iconImageView.image)];
```

The error is:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Can't modify an immutable model.'
```

Comment: Did you check to see if newCatEx is not nil before trying to access its member variables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are calling `entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:` which returns a `NSEntityDescription`.  That would be the definition of the entity, like how you described it in the GUI when you built the model.

I believe what you want is `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:` which will create a new `NSManagedObject` of the entity.

Comment: yep .. that's waht I was doing

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong. This is from the [dev site](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/NSEntityDescription.html):

**Editing Entity Descriptions:**

```
Entity descriptions are editable until they are used by an object graph manager.
This allows you to create or modify them dynamically. 
However, once a description is used (when the managed object model to which it belongs 
is associated with a persistent store coordinator), it must not (indeed cannot) be changed.
This is enforced at runtime: any attempt to mutate a model or any of its sub-objects 
after the model is associated with a persistent store coordinator causes an exception to 
be thrown. If you need to modify a model that is in use, create a copy, modify the copy, 
and then discard the objects with the old model.
```

The exception mentioned towards the end is what you get. Further towards the end is what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> You can get a mutable copy of the model by calling `-mutableCopy` on
>   the `NSManagedObjectModel` instance.

Found here [How to edit a NSManagedObjectModel that was loaded from a momd in iOS5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848237/how-to-edit-a-nsmanagedobjectmodel-that-was-loaded-from-a-momd-in-ios5)